# Mobile version layout misaligned

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, mobile-web

The answer textbox on mobile version is mis-aligned.

Screenshot below:

[image]

On Android 4.3 Firefox 23

Comment: Seems like it hasn't been aligned so much as broken the layout.

Comment: Looks like someone dropped the line break after the title above it. The textarea is styled to fit the screen perfectly. The problem is it's being pushed right by "Your Answer" which *should* just be above it.

Comment: Reproduced on ATT Galaxy S3 4.1.2 using Firefox 27, but the line break is rendered correctly with the stock browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fixed now. Marking as completed.